# Is there a recommended image backup path to ensure I can restore my previous install if the new image fails?

Tags: upgrade, lts, disk-image

I'm still on 14.04 and I'm using my laptop for things related to a production server.  I need a way to have an absolutely rock solid backup plan before my upgrade to next LTS.  I'm sure nobody wants to spend 8 hours sorting out dependencies, but before I pull the trigger, I need to know that I can easily roll the changes back.

How can I roll back to a previous image if I get weird errors after the upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone your system (root) partition to external media using Clonezilla.

Comment: I'm not particularly asking for me.  I could dd if of whatever.  I was looking for a more "step by step" answer for new users.